How to recover a .bashrc file deleted in WSL from explorer.exe?
I accidentally deleted my .bashrc file while managing files in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) through Windows File Explorer. After the deletion, I took the following recovery steps:

Checked the Recycle Bin: I looked for the .bashrc file there but didn’t find it, indicating it likely didn't go to the Recycle Bin when deleted from WSL.
Looked for Backups: I checked my Windows File History for any backups of the .bashrc file but found none available.
Recreated the File: Finally, I manually recreated the .bashrc file using a basic template, successfully restoring my terminal settings, although I lost my previous customizations.


If it's only your .bashrc file.
You might be able to recover it this way :
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/

Otherwise, you might try using forensic tools.
On Windows - Although I'm pretty sure you should do it from WSL -, you can try Recuva. I've used it a few times, it works quite well.
On Linux, you may try ext4magic (see ubuntu manpage). Possibly something like this :
ext4magic /dev/<device> -r -f /home/<yourname>/.bashrc -d /home/<yourname>/.bashrc.old

As indicated here, you might also try something like this :
grep -a -C 300 -F 'known fixed string in your bashrc' /dev/<device> > ~/recover

You may change -C by the amount of line you think there was above and below to the specified string.
There's also extundelete (see this answer) but I don't think it'd be useful doing that on WSL. Because you'd need to unmount the device.

I wonder if any of these work on WSL though. I really don't know, I've never used the thing, but does it even have a real ext4 filesystem? Is there a /dev/ interface that works as expected? Basically, are you sure any of these approaches would actually work for a WSL system? (I stress that I am not implying they won't, I honestly don't know.)

Thanks for your suggestions! I appreciate the options you've provided. I tried them all, but none seem to be suitable for WSL. The first option, cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/, only restores the default settings, which isn't quite what I was looking for.

@terdon - I'm not sure too, I don't have WSL, but I believe ext4magic would be the best option if it was possible
